# What's the difference between Path.Direction.CCW and CW when draw Rect or oval?

Tags: java, android, path

I know `CW` means **clockwise**,and the `CCW` means **counter-clockwise**,
But I think they  achieved the same effect! Both of them can get a whole Rect.
the source code of path.addRect:

```
private void addRect(float left,float top,
    float right,float bottom,int dir){
    moveTo(left,top);
    Direction direction=getDirection(dir);
    switch (direction) {
        case CW:
            lineTo(right,top);
            lineTo(right,bottom);
            lineTo(left,bottom);
            break;
        case CCW:
            lineTo(left,bottom);
            lineTo(right,bottom);
            lineTo(right,top);
            break;
        }
        close();
        resetLastPointFromPath();
   }
}
```

I confused why android provide this parameter.

I had tried to get the answer from google,but failed.
If you know the difference ,please help me out,thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The direction is relevant when you use the Path with a method such as Canvas.drawTextOnPath.
The text will follow the rectangle based on the set direction.